# WPF single .exe Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a strange issue regarding packaging of the WPF .NET4 assemblies in single .exe using an template http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/15e7309a-fda2-46fa-ad49-a8dd3af26feb
Everything works fine except the Microsoft.Bcl library and especially (Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll). I've tried to add (Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll) and mark it as a Resource and/or Embeded Resource, however if the specified dll does not lie near the main .exe the app exits ungracefully. Any Ideas?

The main code responsible for packing .dlls is (taken from Template):

```
private static Assembly OnResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
    {
        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        // Get the Name of the AssemblyFile
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(e.Name);
        var dllName = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";

        // Load from Embedded Resources - This function is not called if the Assembly is already
        // in the same folder as the app.
        var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(dllName));
        if (resources.Any())
        {

            // 99% of cases will only have one matching item, but if you don't,
            // you will have to change the logic to handle those cases.
            var resourceName = resources.First();
            using (var stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream == null) return null;
                var block = new byte[stream.Length];

                // Safely try to load the assembly.
                try
                {
                    stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
                    return Assembly.Load(block);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                catch (BadImageFormatException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        // in the case the resource doesn't exist, return null.
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't really do this with .NET's system libraries. Just make sure the proper version of the .NET framework is installed.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean? Microsoft.Bcl library is added via nuget, hence it is needed to be included.